# SQL COUNT among multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to know what is the SQL if I want data to count from the occurence of a number with respect to data in another table.

TABLE1

```
Day1         Day2
--------------------
1            2
2            3
1            3
3            1
```

TABLE2

```
ID       NAME
------------------
1        John
2        Mary
3        Tom
```

The result I want from SQL will be this

```
ID       NAME        OCCUR
1        John        3
2        Mary        2
3        Tom         3
```

How will the SQL look like for getting this result?

Comment: exactly how do those day values relate to the names? table1.day[12] = table2.id?

Comment: maybe you can see it as some staff with their corresponding ID, just as TABLE2, then they are assigned to different periods in different days, and I want to retrieve how many periods do each one has in Day1 and Day2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you want to count how many rows in `table1` have a matching value in either column.  One easy way is:

```
select t2.*,
       (select count(*)
        from table1 t1
        where t2.id in (t1.day1, t1.day2)
       ) as occur
from table2 t2;
```

Answer (score 0):

In table 1, you must make a foreign key for the table 2. Probably the id of user. With that:

```
Select t2.id, t2.name, Sum(t1.day) 
from table1 t1
innerjoin table2 t2 
on t1.id = t2.id
```

Comment: Probably professional rivalry - and the top-voted answer actually advocates your position, but just throwing ot out there... http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87678/discouraging-w3schools-as-a-resource

Answer (score 0):

Select id and name from table2 and get the amount of occurrences in table1 in a subquery:

```
select 
  id, 
  name, 
  (
    select sum
    (
      case when t1.day1 = t2.id then 1 else 0 end +
      case when t1.day2 = t2.id then 1 else 0 end
    )
    from table1 t1
    where t2.id in (t1.day1, t1.day2)
  ) as occur
from table2 t2
```

Answer (score 0):

Combine `day1` and `day2` column to one, then count.

**Query**

```
select t1.ID, t1.Name, count(t2.[day]) as occur
from table2 t1
left join 
(select Day1 as [day] from table1
union all 
select Day2 as [day] from table1) t2
on t1.ID = t2.[day]
group by t1.ID, t1.Name;
```